# Open PDF from Cloud android

Tags: android, google-drive-android-api

I want to open a PDF File uploaded in Google Drive on click of an Imageview.
As soon as I click, the PDF should get downloaded and ask the user to open a related PDF Viewer

Now the problem is, when I click, It asks the user to open in Drive or Chrome. But I want the options should be for PDF Applications like Adobe reader, polaris office etc.

Here is My Code :

```
 u1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String un1 = "https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_i97Zc2yxeSNFJMVXFGQmlXYzQ&authuser=0";

            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            i.setData(Uri.parse(un1));
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `i.setData(Uri.parse(un1));` with `i.setDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf");`, where `uri` is a `Uri` pointing to your downloaded copy of the PDF file. For example, if you downloaded the PDF file to external storage, you could use `Uri.fromFile()` to get a `Uri` pointing to the same file as does a `File` object.